# CASE in WHERE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'm searching for the most-recent and second-most-recent records of a table. I'm using two instances of TABLE (A and B), differentiated by DATE or, in the event that multiple entries exist on the same DATE, by SEQUENCE. I'm using CASE in my WHERE clause to differentiate between two events: 1. A and B have different dates, 2. A and B have the same date, but different SEQUENCE numbers. Something in my CASE clause is not working out. I would be most grateful for any help you could provide:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE A, TABLE B
WHERE A.PERSON_ID = B.PERSON_ID
  AND A.DATE >= B.DATE

  AND A.DATE = (SELECT MAX(A1.DATE) FROM TABLE A1
                WHERE A.PERSON_ID = A1.PERSON_ID)

  AND A.SEQUENCE = (SELECT MAX(A2.SEQUENCE) FROM TABLE A2
                    WHERE A.PERSON_ID = A2.PERSON_ID
                      AND A.DATE = A2.DATE)

 CASE IF A.DATE > B.DATE 
 THEN (B.DATE = (SELECT MAX(B1.DATE) FROM TABLE B1
                 WHERE B.PERSON_ID = B1.PERSON_ID
                 AND B.SEQUENCE = (SELECT MAX(B2.SEQUENCE) FROM TABLE B2
                                   WHERE B.PERSON_ID = B2.PERSON_ID
                                     AND B.DATE = B2.DATE))

 ELSE (B.SEQUENCE = (SELECT MAX(B2.SEQUENCE) FROM TABLE B2
       WHERE B.PERSION_ID = B2.PERSON_ID
         AND B.DATE = B2.DATE
         AND B2.SEQUENCE < A.SEQUENCE))

  END
```

Here is the error:

> Error during Execute S1000(933)[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended (0.09 secs)

Comment: And for which Database is it?

Comment: What in your case clause is "not working out"? An error, invalid data?  Also, if SQL Server -- `CASE IF A.Data...` should be `CASE WHEN A.Data...`.  You should also use a proper join clause instead of joining in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: Don't you need a comma before the CASE statement?

Answer (score 2):

Using `CASE` in the `WHERE` clause is almost always a mistake. `CASE` exists in SQL primarily to allow Boolean logic where it is not otherwise permitted (such as in a column list). Since the whole purpose of the `WHERE` clause is to express Boolean logic, `CASE` just confuses things.

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. My best guess is that the following query would suit your needs:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_a a JOIN table_b b ON a.person_id = b.person_id
WHERE      a.date = (SELECT MAX (a1.date)
                     FROM   table_a a1
                     WHERE  a.person_id = a1.person_id)
       AND a.sequence =
              (SELECT MAX (a2.sequence)
               FROM   table_a a2
               WHERE  a.person_id = a2.person_id AND a.date = a2.date)
       AND (   (    a.date > b.date
                AND b.date =
                       (SELECT MAX (b1.date)
                        FROM   table_b b1
                        WHERE      b.person_id = b1.person_id
                               AND b.sequence =
                                      (SELECT MAX (b2.sequence)
                                       FROM   table_b b2
                                       WHERE      b.person_id = b2.person_id
                                              AND b.date = b2.date)))
            OR (b.sequence =
                   (SELECT MAX (b2.sequence)
                    FROM   table_b b2
                    WHERE      b.persion_id = b2.person_id
                           AND b.date = b2.date
                           AND b2.sequence < a.sequence)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Query error rectified with slight syntax changes in the case statement

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE A, TABLE B
WHERE A.PERSON_ID = B.PERSON_ID
  AND A.DATE >= B.DATE
  AND A.DATE = (SELECT MAX(A1.DATE) FROM TABLE A1
                WHERE A.PERSON_ID = A1.PERSON_ID)
  AND A.SEQUENCE = (SELECT MAX(A2.SEQUENCE) FROM TABLE A2
                    WHERE A.PERSON_ID = A2.PERSON_ID
                      AND A.DATE = A2.DATE)
 AND 1 = (CASE WHEN A.DATE > B.DATE 
 THEN (CASE WHEN (B.DATE = (SELECT MAX(B1.DATE) FROM TABLE B1
                 WHERE B.PERSON_ID = B1.PERSON_ID
                 AND B.SEQUENCE = (SELECT MAX(B2.SEQUENCE) FROM TABLE B2
                                   WHERE B.PERSON_ID = B2.PERSON_ID
                                     AND B.DATE = B2.DATE))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 ELSE (CASE WHEN (B.SEQUENCE = (SELECT MAX(B2.SEQUENCE) FROM TABLE B2
       WHERE B.PERSON_ID = B2.PERSON_ID
         AND B.DATE = B2.DATE
         AND B2.SEQUENCE < A.SEQUENCE)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  END)
```

### Note

4th line from last

```
"WHERE B.PERSION_ID = B2.PERSON_ID"
```

changed to

```
"WHERE B.PERSON_ID = B2.PERSON_ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm searching for the most-recent and second-most-recent records of a table.

Much simpler to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...)`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e28d/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup - Test Data**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME ( PERSON_ID, "DATE", "SEQUENCE" ) AS
          SELECT 1, DATE '2015-06-26', 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2015-06-26', 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2015-06-27', 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, DATE '2015-06-26', 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, DATE '2015-06-26', 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, DATE '2015-06-26', 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, DATE '2015-06-27', 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, DATE '2015-06-27', 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, DATE '2015-06-27', 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, DATE '2015-06-26', 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, DATE '2015-06-26', 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, DATE '2015-06-27', 3 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1 - First and Second entries on different rows**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY "DATE" DESC, "SEQUENCE" DESC ) AS RN
  FROM   TABLE_NAME t
)
WHERE RN <= 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e28d/5/0)**:

```
| PERSON_ID |                   DATE | SEQUENCE | RN |
|-----------|------------------------|----------|----|
|         1 | June, 27 2015 00:00:00 |        1 |  1 |
|         1 | June, 26 2015 00:00:00 |        2 |  2 |
|         2 | June, 26 2015 00:00:00 |        1 |  1 |
|         3 | June, 27 2015 00:00:00 |        3 |  1 |
|         3 | June, 27 2015 00:00:00 |        2 |  2 |
|         4 | June, 27 2015 00:00:00 |        3 |  1 |
|         4 | June, 26 2015 00:00:00 |        2 |  2 |
```

**Query 2 - First and Second entries on the same row**:

```
SELECT PERSON_ID,
       FIRST_DATE,
       FIRST_SEQUENCE,
       SECOND_DATE,
       SECOND_SEQUENCE
FROM   (
  SELECT PERSON_ID,
         "DATE" AS FIRST_DATE,
         "SEQUENCE" AS FIRST_SEQUENCE,
         LEAD( "DATE"     ) OVER ( PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY "DATE" DESC, "SEQUENCE" DESC ) AS SECOND_DATE,
         LEAD( "SEQUENCE" ) OVER ( PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY "DATE" DESC, "SEQUENCE" DESC ) AS SECOND_SEQUENCE,
         ROW_NUMBER()       OVER ( PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY "DATE" DESC, "SEQUENCE" DESC ) AS RN
  FROM   TABLE_NAME t
)
WHERE RN = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e28d/5/1)**:

```
| PERSON_ID |             FIRST_DATE | FIRST_SEQUENCE |            SECOND_DATE | SECOND_SEQUENCE |
|-----------|------------------------|----------------|------------------------|-----------------|
|         1 | June, 27 2015 00:00:00 |              1 | June, 26 2015 00:00:00 |               2 |
|         2 | June, 26 2015 00:00:00 |              1 |                 (null) |          (null) |
|         3 | June, 27 2015 00:00:00 |              3 | June, 27 2015 00:00:00 |               2 |
|         4 | June, 27 2015 00:00:00 |              3 | June, 26 2015 00:00:00 |               2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I'm not really sure how OVER and PARTITION BY would play into this. Here is what I ended up using:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE A, TABLE B
WHERE A.PERSON_ID = B.PERSON_ID
  AND A.DATE >= B.DATE

  AND A.DATE = (SELECT MAX(A1.DATE) FROM TABLE A1
                WHERE A.PERSON_ID = A1.PERSON_ID)

  AND A.SEQUENCE = (SELECT MAX(A2.SEQUENCE) FROM TABLE A2
                    WHERE A.PERSON_ID = A2.PERSON_ID
                      AND A.DATE = A2.DATE)

  AND ((A.DATE = B.DATE
  AND B.DATE = (SELECT MAX(B1.DATE) FROM TABLE B1
                WHERE B.PERSON_ID = B1.PERSON_ID)

  AND B.SEQUENCE = (SELECT MAX(B2.SEQUENCE) FROM TABLE B2
                    WHERE B.PERSON_ID = B2.PERSON_ID
                      AND B.DATE = B2.DATE
                      AND B.SEQUENCE < A.SEQUENCE))

   OR (A.DATE > B.DATE
  AND B.DATE = (SELECT MAX(B1.DATE) FROM TABLE B1
                WHERE B.PERSON_ID = B1.PERSON_ID
                  AND B1.DATE < A.DATE)

  AND B.SEQUENCE = (SELECT MAX(B2.SEQUENCE) FROM TABLE B2
                    WHERE B.PERSON_ID = B_ES.PERSON_ID
                      AND B.DATE = B2.DATE)))

ORDER BY A.PERSON_ID, B.SEQUENCE
```